# Official rules for using optional skills

Tags: dnd-4e, skills

I'm having troubles in my D&D 4e table because the skill system, even though it's simple and fast, is also limited. And there are quite a few things my characters want to do and sometimes I just don't know how to represent them.

As in, a player wants his Swashbuckler (hybrid rogue/ranger) to be great at sailing. And right now, another player wants his ex-noble Dwarven Fighter from Waterdeep to be very good at analyzing prices.

How to solve those? Is there any sort of "Official rule" for optional skills?

Comment: I don't have any books here and don't know of "official rules", but a Skill Proficiency grants a +5, so something as simple as "pick some things your character would know from his background, and you get a +5 when you make an Ability Check for those" would probably solve it.

Comment: In what kind of situation would your player want to make a 'sailing' check? That seems pretty vague. I would expect them to try to tie a knot (Dexterity?, maybe Thievery?), hold the wheel in a storm (Strength, maybe Athletics) or something like that, not 'sail'.

Comment: I don't consider Sailing a vague skill.

Answer (score 8):

There aren't really any official resources on optional expanded skill lists. And that's OK.

Here's why:

- The skill list is top level super broad skill categories. Trained in Athletics? Good at parts of sailing. Trained in Nature? Good at other parts of sailing. Trained in history? Good at other parts of sailing.
- The skill list is not meant to be complete. The categories are broad, but they can't encompass everything. For those checks that somehow don't fit a skill category, you use the a straight ability check, pick the ability that most closely matches and use that.
- You're free to apply situational bonuses as you see fit. Character's backgrounds, past experiences and other factors can and should lead them to ask you for a situational bonus when their trained skills don't apply. It's up to you the value of the bonus, but I'd recommend either a +2 or a +5. +2 is the recommended default bonus for any situation that comes up, however +5 is the bonus for a trained skill. Pick one of these two and use that if there is a situation where a PC would logically know how to do something but is not explicitly trained in it.

So, overall, while there is not an optional, more granular, skill system available in the official rules. The Rules *have* provided you with the tools you need to make a satisfactory ruling and keep your game moving.

Answer (score 4):

While @wax eagle's suggestion is great, there is another alternative...

**A player wants to be good at something? *Let* them.**

Both of your examples have two qualities that make them good candidates for this approach:

1. The desired "skill" is something that doesn't come up very often (in most campaigns). How often is your party going to need to sail, or to analyze prices? If the answer isn't "most sessions", then there isn't much harm in simply allowing characters to be good at those things.
2. The desired "skill" doesn't clearly fall under the broader definition of one of the core skills. Sailing involves a lot of different things, from judging the weather, adjusting the sails, climbing the rigging, tying knots, etc. Analyzing prices isn't quite so scattershot, but depending on *what* the price is associated with pretty much any knowledge skill could apply, as well as streetwise.

**So, how does this work, exactly?**

Any time a character makes a skill check, *any* skill check, that's *directly* related to the thing they're good at, they're treated as trained in the skill. Various athletics, acrobatics, or nature checks made to sail? Your swashbuckler is trained. Checks for those in other conditions? Only if he's normally trained by the rules.

The tricky part is keeping these bonuses contained. If you're too permissive, then suddenly being good at sailing is enough to be trained at anything involving rope, any kind of balance check, any & all weather prediction, etc.

You also want to try to balance out how often different players get to apply their special "skills". If the swashbuckler's sailing talent comes up a lot more often than the dwarf's ability to judge prices, the dwarf's player is likely to feel (not unreasonably) that s/he got screwed.